# Retornar resultado da consulta SQL na função ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

Estou usando Javascript com JQuery para construir uma aplicação simples.
Preciso realizar a consulta dos dados na database e renderizar na aplicação.
Para isso tenho três arquivos: index.js para as funções JQuery, o app.js para as rotas e o queries.js como módulo para as queries SQL.

Como faço para retornar o 'result' do callback da query no success do ajax?

```
// app.js
app.route('/postit')
    .get((req, res) => {
        try {
            readPosts()
        } catch {
            res.status(400).json({'response': 'Erro. Não foi possível consultar os dados.'})
        }
        res.status(200).json({'response': 'Dados recuperados com sucesso!'})
    })
```

```
// index.js
$(
    function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'postit',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: (result) => {
                console.log(result)
            },
            error: (result) => {
                console.log(result)
            }
        })
    }
)
```

```
// queries.js
module.exports = {
    readPosts() {
            con.query(
                `SELECT * FROM post;`,
                (err, result) => {
                    if (err) throw err
                    console.log(result)
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

No ficheiro queries.js não podes definir a função dessa forma, tens de criar uma chave para o objeto.

```
readPosts: function() {
```